# NSComboBox: Notification of scrolling through content

Tags: swift, macos, combobox

I have an NSComboBox and I need to know the current location within the list as the user scrolls through the combo box content. As an example:

[image]

As the user scrolls through the content, from 101.Name and down the list, I would like some kind of notification of movement and the ability to identify the highlighted entry to execute additional logic.  Note that at this point the user has not made a selection; the user is simply scrolling through the list.

I've reviewed the Apple documentation and searched SO, but finding nothing appropriate.  I suspect I'm missing something obvious, but alas, I'm stuck on next steps.

My question: is there a way to receive ongoing notifications as the user scrolls through the combo box list?

Comment: The highlighted entry doesn't change during scroll. Do you want to be notified when the highlighted entry changes or when the list is scrolled? Or do you want to get the coordinates of the highlighted entry?

Comment: @Willeke I can use my mouse to cycle through the entries, from 101.Name to 101.zip, and back again.  I need to know when I move from 101.Address to to 101.City, and be given some indication of position within the list, either the actual string displayed, or some index value. I can use either to access the backing data used to populate the combo box.

Comment: How about `objectValueOfSelectedItem` and `indexOfSelectedItem`? Have you tried any notifications and/or the delegate?

Comment: @Willeke Well this is embarrassing.  I had implemented SelectionIsChanging in the delegate, but only got it to fire when I actually hit enter. I've since added SelectionDidChange, which fires as I move through the list, and indexOfSelectedItem give me what I need.  I didn't expect help from SelectionDidChange based on what I observed with SelectionIsChanging.  The blush on my face is pure embarrassment. As always, thank you for your help.

Comment: I also expected `SelectionIsChanging`  and `SelectionDidChange` the other way around.